# Expand / Collapse ExpansionTiles dentro de un List

Tags: flutter, dart

Dispongo de un proyecto de Flutter en el que leo el archivo de `pubspec.yaml` y cargo el contenido obtenido en un `Map` gracias, entre otras cosas, a la funcionalidad ofrecida por el paquete de **[yaml](https://pub.dev/packages/yaml)**.

[./lib/src/providers/file_provider.dart]

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';


class _FileProvider {

  _FileProvider();

  //...

  Future<Map> cargarDataYamlToMap(String fileUrl) async {
    final resp = await rootBundle.loadString(fileUrl);

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> dataMap = loadYaml( resp );

    return dataMap;
  }

}

final fileProvider = _FileProvider();
```

Luego, el Map obtenido (o, más bien `YamlMap`), recibido dentro de un `FutureBuilder` es mandado al método `_listaDinamic` dónde es recorrido, recursivamente, para llegar a construir un `List<Widget>` con sus `ListTile` y/o `ExpansionTile` según el elemento recorrido sea un par de clave(String)/valor(NO siendo un `Map`) o un par de clave(String)/valor(siendo `Map`).

[./lib/src/pages/pub_spec_page.dart]

```
class PubSpecPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PubSpecPageState createState() => _PubSpecPageState();
}

class _PubSpecPageState extends State<PubSpecPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          S.of(context).pubSpecTitle,
        ),

        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'EXPAND :: Desplegando Todos',
            icon: Icon(Icons.unfold_more),
            onPressed: () {
              print('EXPAND :: Desplegando Todos');
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'COLLAPSE :: Replegando Todos',
            icon: Icon(Icons.unfold_less),
            onPressed: () {
              print('COLLAPSE :: Replegando Todos');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: _listaDinamic(),
    );

  }

  Widget _listaDinamic() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: fileProvider.cargarDataYamlToMap('pubspec.yaml'),
      builder: ( context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> snapShot ) {
        //print(snapShot.data);

        if(snapShot.hasData) {
          return ListView(
            children: _crearItems( snapShot.data, 0 ),
          );

        } else if (snapShot.hasError) { 
          return Text('ERROR: ${snapShot.error}');
        }
        String txtMsg = 'Esperando el resultado...';
        return Text(
          txtMsg,
        );

      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _crearItems( Map<dynamic, dynamic> data, int indentLevel, [int indexTile] ) {
    final List<Widget> items = [];

    data.entries.forEach((e) {
      var widgetTemp;

      if( e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'YamlList' ) {

        //NECESARIO convertir el valor en un List...
        List<dynamic> values = List.from(e.value);
        List<Widget> subItems = [];
        for(var subItem in values) {
            widgetTemp = ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', (indentLevel+1), 'iconColor' ),),
              title: Text( '$subItem' ),
            );

            if (indentLevel > 0) {
              widgetTemp = Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: languagesProvider.getDoubleOptionByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'paddingLeft' )),
                child: widgetTemp,
              );
            }

            if(widgetTemp != null)
              subItems.add( widgetTemp );
            widgetTemp = null;
        }//for

        widgetTemp = ExpansionTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'iconColor' ),),
          title: Text( e.key ),
          children: subItems,
        );

      } else if( e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'String'
              || e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'bool'
              || e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'int'
              || e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'double' ) {

        widgetTemp = ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'iconColor' ),),
          title: Text( e.key ),
          subtitle: Text( '${e.value}' ),
        );

      } else {//Siendo YamlMap

        Map<String, dynamic> mapValue;
        if( e.value.runtimeType.toString() == 'YamlMap' ) {
          mapValue = Map<String, dynamic>.from(e.value);
        }

        widgetTemp = ExpansionTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'iconColor' ),),
          title: Text( e.key ),
          children: _crearItems( mapValue, (indentLevel + 1), (indexTile) ),
        );

      }//No o Si es YamlMap

      if (indentLevel > 0) {
        widgetTemp = Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: languagesProvider.getDoubleOptionByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'paddingLeft' )),
          child: widgetTemp,
        );
      }

      if(widgetTemp != null)
        items.add( widgetTemp );
    });

    return items;
  }

}
```

Todo correcto hasta aquí.

Por un lado, lo que pretendo es que al expandir otro `ExpansionTile`, el anterior que se haya abierto, sea cerrado automáticamente.

En mis búsquedas sobre temas relacionados, he visto cuestiones relacionadas con las propiedades `key`, `initiallyExpanded` y `onExpansionChanged` de los `ExpansionTile`. Pero no he conseguido lo que pretendía.

He llegado a probar lo que sigue:

- de primeras, he añadido una nueva propiedad `selected` en la clase de `PubSpecPage` y, cuando se recorre el `data`, he añadido una propiedad `key` a cada nuevo `ListTile` y `ExpansionTile` al que se le asigna un `indexTile + 1` para que, supuestamente, cada `key` de cada elemento sea único.

  ```
  class _PubSpecPageState extends State<PubSpecPage> {

    int selected = 0;

    //...

      widgetTemp = ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', (indentLevel+1), 'iconColor' ),),
        title: Text( '$subItem' ),
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        key: Key((indexTile + 1).toString()),
      );

    //...
  ```
- luego, en los `ExpansionTile`, además, añado el `initiallyExpanded` y el `onExpansionChanged`:

  ```
  //...

  indexTile++;
  //-----------------------------------------------------
  widgetTemp = ExpansionTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: languagesProvider.getColorByLanguageCode( actualLanguageCodeConstant, 'indentLevelOptions', indentLevel, 'iconColor' ),),
    title: Text( e.key ),
    children: subItems,
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    key: Key((indexTile).toString()),
    initiallyExpanded : indexTile==selected,
    onExpansionChanged: ((newState){
      if(newState)
        setState(() {
          Duration(seconds:  20000);
          selected = indexTile;
        });
        else setState(() {
          selected = -1;
        });
    }),
  );
  ```

Pero el resultado de todo esto es el recibir toda esta serie de excepciones:

- de primeras estas dos excepciones:

  ```
  ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
  The following assertion was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 683.4), devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, physicalDepth: 1.7976931348623157e+308, alwaysUse24HourFormat: true, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false,disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false)):
  'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.


  Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
  In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

  The relevant error-causing widget was
      ListView 
  lib\…\pages\pub_spec_page.dart:81
  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
  #2      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._debugVerifyChildOrder 
  package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:263
  #3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled=.<anonymous closure> 
  package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:238
  #4      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled= 
  package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:240
  #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild 
  package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1255
  #6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update 
  package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1191
  ...
  ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

  ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
  A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
  The relevant error-causing widget was
      ListView 
  lib\…\pages\pub_spec_page.dart:81
  ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  ```
- y, luego, esta excepción repetida 23 de veces seguidas (cantidad de supuestos elementos a construir dentro del `List<Widget>`):

  ```
  ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
  'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3949 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
  The relevant error-causing widget was
      ListView 
  lib\…\pages\pub_spec_page.dart:81
  ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  ```

Ojalá alguien tenga pueda suministrar la ayuda necesaria para conseguir el propósito deseado de cerrar el elemento anterior en el momento que se despliega otro.

Por otro lado, en el `appBar` de la página, he dispuesto dos iconos: uno para expandir todos los `ExpansionTile` y otro para colapsar todos los `ExpansionTile`.
¿Alguna idea de cómo llegar a conseguir estas dos funcionalidades de expandir/colapsar todos los `ExpansionTile` al pulsar el correspondiente icono?

Saludos.

Comment: Divide y vencerás, reduce tu issue a un código simple y corto que se pueda reproducir para poder ayudarte : )

Comment: No sé de qué manera quieres que divida el asunto. ¿Una pista? ¿Quieres que ponga un ejemplo más simple o qué?

Comment: Así es, un ejemplo simple, un main.dart,  el error está en el layout, trata de reproducirlo en un proyecto aparte sin tu logica del negocio :)

Comment: Para la siguiente vez, como ahora, que oigo términos como "lógica de negocio", ya no me acuerdo lo que llegue a comprender en su momento. Perdona, pero, de nuevo ¿a qué te refieres, "aparte, sin tu lógica de negocio"? ¿Y qué parte de todo lo que he puesto se refiere al llayout que mencionas?

Comment: En resumen, crea un archivo basico con solo el expansiontile que quieres dentro de una lista, con datos basicos, lo mas sencillo posible para poder solucionarlo

Comment: Entonces, debería ser al menos un ejemplo simple de proyecto con, al menos, un Map de datos, que se cargue en un ListView que disponga de. al menos, dos ExpansionTile para que hubiera algo de juego de abrir/cerrar todos y para establecer la otra funcionalidad de cerrar el ExpansionTile abierto cuando se abre el siguiente. ¿Con eso estaría bien para ser analizado y obtener las deseadas soluciones? ... ¿Todo esto sustituiría todo lo que he puesto como código de la pregunta o lo añado aparte como parte editada de la pregunta?

Comment: Asi es. Es mas facil poder ayudarte cua ndo podamos correr el codigo en un simple archivo.

Comment: Vale. Espero tus posibles respuestas tras añadir ese código básico. Gracias. Hasta ese momento ... Saludos (por ahora, me voy a dormir).

Comment: Podrías marcar la pregunta como solucionada?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, para lo que deseas hacer primero vas a tener que crear un `ExpansionTile` personalizado para que puedas acceder a su `State` ya que el actual lo tiene privado. Así también crear métodos para ocultar y/o mostrar el tile.

Luego de eso debes crear `GlobalKeys` y asignarlo a tu nuevo `ExpansionTitle`, finalmente al momento de que seleccionas uno , verificar los demás y cerrarlos.

Aquí te dejo el código completo.

AppExpansionTitle Widget

```dart
const Duration _kExpand = const Duration(milliseconds: 200);

class AppExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppExpansionTile({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    @required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.onExpansionChanged,
    this.children: const <Widget>[],
    this.trailing,
    this.initiallyExpanded: false,
  })  : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Widget leading;
  final Widget title;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onExpansionChanged;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget trailing;
  final bool initiallyExpanded;

  @override
  AppExpansionTileState createState() => AppExpansionTileState();
}

class AppExpansionTileState extends State<AppExpansionTile>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  CurvedAnimation _easeOutAnimation;
  CurvedAnimation _easeInAnimation;
  ColorTween _borderColor;
  ColorTween _headerColor;
  ColorTween _iconColor;
  ColorTween _backgroundColor;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;

  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _easeOutAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    _easeInAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);
    _borderColor = ColorTween();
    _headerColor = ColorTween();
    _iconColor = ColorTween();
    _iconTurns = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(_easeInAnimation);
    _backgroundColor = ColorTween();

    _isExpanded =
        PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
    if (_isExpanded) _controller.value = 1.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void expand() {
    _setExpanded(true);
  }

  void collapse() {
    _setExpanded(false);
  }

  void toggle() {
    _setExpanded(!_isExpanded);
  }

  void _setExpanded(bool isExpanded) {
    if (_isExpanded != isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _isExpanded = isExpanded;
        if (_isExpanded)
          _controller.forward();
        else
          _controller.reverse().then<void>((value) {
            setState(() {
              // Rebuild without widget.children.
            });
          });
        PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
      });
      if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null) {
        widget.onExpansionChanged(_isExpanded);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final Color borderSideColor =
        _borderColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent;
    final Color titleColor = _headerColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _backgroundColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ??
              Colors.transparent,
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
            bottom: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
          )),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconTheme.merge(
            data: IconThemeData(color: _iconColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation)),
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: toggle,
              leading: widget.leading,
              title: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .subhead
                    .copyWith(color: titleColor),
                child: widget.title,
              ),
              trailing: widget.trailing ??
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: _iconTurns,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipRect(
            child: Align(
              heightFactor: _easeInAnimation.value,
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColor
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColor
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColor.end = widget.backgroundColor;

    final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: _buildChildren,
      child: closed ? null : Column(children: widget.children),
    );
  }
}
```

Sample Widget

```dart
class MySample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySampleState createState() => _MySampleState();
}

class _MySampleState extends State<MySample> {
  List<GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState>> _keys =
      List.generate(dataEntry.length, (_) => GlobalKey());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dataEntry.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final entry = dataEntry[index];
          if (entry.children == null || entry.children.isEmpty) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(entry.title),
              subtitle: Text(entry.subTitle),
            );
          }
          return _buildTiles(entry, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root, int index) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return ListTile(title: Text(root.title));
    return AppExpansionTile(
      key: index != -1 ? _keys[index] : null,
      onExpansionChanged: (val) {
        // Si es el parent
        if (root.idParent == -1 && val && index != -1) {
          //Cerrar los otros
          for (Entry item in dataEntry) {
            if (item.id != root.id) {
              for (int i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++) {
                if (i != index && _keys[i].currentState != null) {
                  print("i :$i .. ${_keys[i]}");
                  _keys[i].currentState.collapse();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      title: Text(root.title),
      children:
          root.children.map((subItem) => _buildTiles(subItem, -1)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Para expandir todos

```dart
void _expandAll() { 
  for (int i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++) { 
      if(_keys[i].currentState != null)
        _keys[i].currentState.expand(); 
  } 
}
```

Para contraer todos

```dart
void _colapseAll() { 
  for (int i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++) { 
      if(_keys[i].currentState != null)
        _keys[i].currentState.collapse(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106098/discussion-on-answer-by-diegoveloper-expand-collapse-expansiontiles-dentro-de).