# Obtener un item de una lista de objetos

Tags: flutter, dart

Supongamos que tengo una clase `Entry` tal como ésta:

```
class Entry {
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;
  final List<Entry> children;//Cada entrada puede tener, a su vez, listas de entradas en su interior
  final int id;
  final int idParent;
  bool isExpanded;
  Entry(this.id, this.idParent, this.title, [this.subTitle = '', this.children = const <Entry>[], this.isExpanded = false]);
}
```

Por otro lado una lista de `Entry`:

```
///Posible ejemplo de lista multinivel de entradas:
final List<Entry> dataSampleB = <Entry>[
  Entry(
    1, -1,
    'A-Title',
    'A-SubTitle',
  ),
  //-----------------------------------------
  Entry(
    2, -1,
    'B-Title',
    '',
    <Entry>[
      Entry(4, 2, 'B.1-Title', 'B.1-SubTitle'),
    ],
    false,
  ),
  //-----------------------------------------
  Entry(
    3, -1,
    'C-Title',
    '',
    <Entry>[
      Entry(
        5, 3,
        'C.1-Title',
        '',
        <Entry>[
          Entry(20, 5, 'C.1.1-Title', 'C.1.1-SubTitle'),
        ],
        false,
      ),
      Entry(
        6, 3, 
        'C.2-Title',
        '',
        <Entry>[
          Entry(
            11, 6,
            'C.2.1-Title',
            '',
            <Entry>[
              Entry(17, 11, 'C.2.1.1-Tit.', 'C.2.1.1-SubTit.'),
              Entry(18, 11, 'C.2.1.2-Tit.', 'C.2.1.2-SubTit.'),
              Entry(19, 11, 'C.2.1.3-Tit.', 'C.2.1.3-SubTit.'),
            ],
            false,
          ),
        ],
        false,
      ),
      Entry( 7, 3, 'C.3-Title', 'C.3-SubTitle', ),
    ],
    false,
  ),
  //-----------------------------------------
  Entry(
    8, -1,
    'D-Title',
    '',
    <Entry>[
      Entry(
        10, 8,
        'D.1-Title',
        '',
        <Entry>[
          Entry(
            12, 10,
            'D.1.1-Title',
            '',
            <Entry>[
              Entry(14, 12, 'D.1.1.1-Tit.', 'D.1.1.1-SubTit.'),
              Entry(
                15, 12,
                'D.1.1.2-Tit.',
                '',
                <Entry>[
                  Entry(16, 15, 'D.1.1.2.1-Tit.', 'D.1.1.2.1-SubTit.'),
                  Entry(22, 11, 'D.1.1.2.2-Tit.', 'D.1.1.2.2-SubTit.'),
                  Entry(23, 11, 'D.1.1.2.3-Tit.', 'D.1.1.2.3-SubTit.'),
                ],
                false,
              ),
              Entry(
                24, 12,
                'D.1.1.3-Tit.',
                '',
                <Entry>[
                  Entry(25, 24, 'D.1.1.3.1-Tit.', 'D.1.1.3.1-SubTit.'),
                ],
                false,
              ),
            ],
            false,
          ),
        ],
        false,
      ),
      Entry(13, 8, 'D.2-Title', 'D.2-SubTitle'),
      Entry(21, 8, 'D.3-Title', 'D.3-SubTitle'),
    ],
    false,
  ),
  //-----------------------------------------
  Entry(
    9, -1,
    'E-Title',
    'E-SubTitle',
  ),
];
```

Digamos que se está recorriendo la lista `dataEntry` a través de un `List.builder`, de esta forma, se obtiene un determinado `Entry` gracias a `dataEntry[index]` y, de ahí, se accede al valor de cada una de sus propiedades:

```
int idEntrySelected = dataEntry[index].id;
int idParentSelected = dataEntry[index].idParent;
//...
```

Lo que pretendo es acceder a un determinado `Entry` localizándolo por el valor de su propiedad `id` obtenido por el `idParent` del `Entry` que se está recorriendo. Osea, localizar el `Entry` que sea el padre de otro. ¿Es posible?

El próposito de esto:
Se está recorriendo una lista para montar un ListView con sus correspondientes `ListTile` (cuando el `Entry` recorrido no tiene `children`) y sus `ExpansionTile` (cuando el `Entry` si los tiene). En el caso de los `ExpansionTile`, se volverá a llamar al método de construcción del `ListView`, pasándole, como parámetro, el `Entry` de tipo lista de `Entry` que se deberá recorrer.
Cuando se pulse en algún `ExpansionTile` para que se expanda, en el `onExpansionChanged` del elemento pulsado, se almacenará el ID del elemento pulsado para saber qué elemento está expandido y poder llegar a cerrar los demás. Igualmente, es necesario que el elemento padre siga abierto. Por ello, la razón de poder acceder al elemento padre a través del `idParent` del elemento recorrido. Y, tras haber podido acceder al padre, manipular su propiedad de `isExpanded` para que quede abierto si, al menos uno de sus hijos lo está al mismo tiempo.

Saludos.

Comment: Sí, solo recorres la sublista de cada entry y comparas el id con el id del parent y listo :).  Te recomiendo que hagas ese ejemplo en un proyecto Dart sencillo (no flutter) , para que puedas probarlo ahí y luego ya lo usas con tus widgets. https://dartpad.dev/

Comment: Si, claro, sabiendo el `idParent` del `entry` en el que está el cursor en el momento actual, dentro de la sublista que se está recorriendo, dispongo de lo que es el `id` del `entry` que es el padre del `entry` que está imprimiendo. Lo que no veo del todo es cómo acceder a ese `entry` que es el padre para disponer, digamos, de una instancia de él y, por ejemplo, acceder o modificar alguna de sus propiedades; incluso, dentro mismo del proceso de construcción de toda lista gracias al List.builder o a alguno de los métodos implicados en dicho proceso.

Comment: Qué quieres lograr hacer? veo que te estás complicando mucho. Primero deberías tener la lógica de tus listas/objetos antes de pensar en el ListView o algún widget.  
Te recomiendo que lo hagas aquí : https://dartpad.dev/  pinta datos para ver resultados

Comment: Osea, si tienes montada la implementación con un método recursivo que se llama a sí mismo en los casos en los que el `entry` dispone de `children`, los índices de la siguiente lista o sublista recorrida, vuelven a empezar desde 0 y ... bueno que, no sé, no veo clara la manera de acceder a instancia de un `entry` por medio de su `id`. Si fuera esto un acceso a una tabla de base de datos, lo vería totalmente claro, haciendo un SELECT por el ID del padre y, de esta forma, incluso, poder manipular sus datos, pero en este caso de clases, no sé del todo como actuar. ¿Un ejemplo?

Comment: Si, ya conozco la herramienta y ya suelo emplearla.

Comment: ok, cual es el input y cual es el output que esperas recibir ?   ejemplo : input =  id de parent ?   out put = el parent?     danos mas info

Comment: Acabo de añadir un párrafo para que se entienda algo más lo que espero conseguir.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105949/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-zacktagnan).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, para lo que deseas hacer primero vas a tener que crear un `ExpansionTile` personalizado para que puedas acceder a su `State` ya que el actual lo tiene privado. Así también crear métodos para ocultar y/o mostrar el tile.

Luego de eso debes crear `GlobalKeys` y asignarlo a tu nuevo `ExpansionTitle`, finalmente al momento de que seleccionas uno , verificar los demás y cerrarlos.

Aquí te dejo el código completo.

AppExpansionTitle Widget

```dart
const Duration _kExpand = const Duration(milliseconds: 200);

class AppExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppExpansionTile({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    @required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.onExpansionChanged,
    this.children: const <Widget>[],
    this.trailing,
    this.initiallyExpanded: false,
  })  : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Widget leading;
  final Widget title;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onExpansionChanged;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Widget trailing;
  final bool initiallyExpanded;

  @override
  AppExpansionTileState createState() => AppExpansionTileState();
}

class AppExpansionTileState extends State<AppExpansionTile>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  CurvedAnimation _easeOutAnimation;
  CurvedAnimation _easeInAnimation;
  ColorTween _borderColor;
  ColorTween _headerColor;
  ColorTween _iconColor;
  ColorTween _backgroundColor;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;

  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _easeOutAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    _easeInAnimation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);
    _borderColor = ColorTween();
    _headerColor = ColorTween();
    _iconColor = ColorTween();
    _iconTurns = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(_easeInAnimation);
    _backgroundColor = ColorTween();

    _isExpanded =
        PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
    if (_isExpanded) _controller.value = 1.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void expand() {
    _setExpanded(true);
  }

  void collapse() {
    _setExpanded(false);
  }

  void toggle() {
    _setExpanded(!_isExpanded);
  }

  void _setExpanded(bool isExpanded) {
    if (_isExpanded != isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _isExpanded = isExpanded;
        if (_isExpanded)
          _controller.forward();
        else
          _controller.reverse().then<void>((value) {
            setState(() {
              // Rebuild without widget.children.
            });
          });
        PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
      });
      if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null) {
        widget.onExpansionChanged(_isExpanded);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final Color borderSideColor =
        _borderColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent;
    final Color titleColor = _headerColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation);

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _backgroundColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ??
              Colors.transparent,
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
            bottom: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
          )),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconTheme.merge(
            data: IconThemeData(color: _iconColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation)),
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: toggle,
              leading: widget.leading,
              title: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .subhead
                    .copyWith(color: titleColor),
                child: widget.title,
              ),
              trailing: widget.trailing ??
                  RotationTransition(
                    turns: _iconTurns,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                  ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipRect(
            child: Align(
              heightFactor: _easeInAnimation.value,
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColor
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColor
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColor.end = widget.backgroundColor;

    final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: _buildChildren,
      child: closed ? null : Column(children: widget.children),
    );
  }
}
```

Sample Widget

```dart
class MySample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySampleState createState() => _MySampleState();
}

class _MySampleState extends State<MySample> {
  List<GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState>> _keys =
      List.generate(dataEntry.length, (_) => GlobalKey());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dataEntry.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final entry = dataEntry[index];
          if (entry.children == null || entry.children.isEmpty) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(entry.title),
              subtitle: Text(entry.subTitle),
            );
          }
          return _buildTiles(entry, index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root, int index) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return ListTile(title: Text(root.title));
    return AppExpansionTile(
      key: index != -1 ? _keys[index] : null,
      onExpansionChanged: (val) {
        // Si es el parent
        if (root.idParent == -1 && val && index != -1) {
          //Cerrar los otros
          for (Entry item in dataEntry) {
            if (item.id != root.id) {
              for (int i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++) {
                if (i != index && _keys[i].currentState != null) {
                  print("i :$i .. ${_keys[i]}");
                  _keys[i].currentState.collapse();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      title: Text(root.title),
      children:
          root.children.map((subItem) => _buildTiles(subItem, -1)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106016/discussion-on-answer-by-diegoveloper-obtener-un-item-de-una-lista-de-objetos).

Comment: No llego a entender del todo el bloque incluido en el `onExpansionChanged` y su interacción con el `_keys` ... Si me lo pudieras explicar paso a paso, estaría bien o edita su respuesta para explicarlo. :)

Comment: Verifico todos los entries parent principales (los que tienen -1 como id de parent), y veo que si el index seleccionado no es igual a ese, sino es entonces obtengo el key asignado con el index que pertenece, con el key puedo acceder al State y cerrar el listitle.

Comment: Por cierto, se me olvidaba comentar que lo que pretendía con la pregunta era resolver un paso de lo que pensaba hacer para resolver otra pregunta que efectué unos días atrás referido, esta pregunta si, al tema de "[Expand / Collapse ExpansionTiles dentro de un List](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/338819/expand-collapse-expansiontiles-dentro-de-un-list)". Así que puede que quieras mover tu respuesta a esta otra pregunta. Y, de paso, darme la pista o respuesta, también, para la segunda parte de ésta en la que pedía como podía ser para expandir o colapsar todos a través de sendos botones.